# Can you unknowingly become a hypocrite due to wiswasa?

Tags: waswasa

If I have doubts about Islam to the extent that I have whispers (waswasa) about it, have I then become a hypocrite?

Answer (score 1):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

Right Arabic word for hypocrite, in Islam, is Munafiq. Munafiq is a false Muslim. Munafiq is a disbeliever. He is not Muslim. He shows himself as a Muslim only for the purpose of disguise.

See also

- [Wikipedia - Munafiq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munafiq)

The concept of Waswasa has nothing to do with hypocrisy. It is a whisper, the evil of doubts, caused by Waswasilhannas, the wicked one described in Sura An-nas, 114, of holy Quran, which insinuates into the chests of people.

See also

- [Tafseer of Sura An-Nas](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH114_SuraAlNaas_Verses1-5.pdf)